# Dynamic form with reordering and deletion

Tags: sapui5

I am curious as to how one would create something like what I
have in this screenshot mockup:

[image]

1. The goal is to enter a single FormRow at a time. Each FormRow gets
   added to a FormRowListForm.
2. This FormRowListForm can be reordered by dragging with a mouse.
3. Rows can be removed by clicking on the "Remove Row"
   button.
4. The FormRowListForm can be commited to database by
   clicking "Commit Form Rows to Database"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sheer looks of it, first i would define a JSONModel where you store the different rows.

Then create a VBox, bind its items aggregation to your model, and each item will be a HBox (I'm simplifying here, you may need to adjust because of layout requirements but you get the idea)

The drag and drop will be done on each HBox, effectively reordering its position in the model.

Adding or deleting a row works the same: just add or delete from the model and the binding takes care of the rest.

Once finished, you can then store your model data in your database in the required format